# How to deserialize JWT with "http://url/path" as field names?

Tags: rust, jwt, serde

I have an actix-web server that will be validating a JWT with each request and extracting claims for internal use.
I have the JWT decode-and-validate process working, based on [this](https://github.com/auth0-developer-hub/api_actix-web_rust_hello-world/blob/basic-role-based-access-control/src/extractors/claims.rs) example by Auth0.

The problem I have is the enterprise application I need to work with has its claims structured as:

```json
{
    "https://some-org-url/domain": "some-domain",
    "https://some-org-url/roles": [
        "...",
    ],
    "https://some-org-url/tag-list": [
        "...",
    ],
    "iss": "https://auth-app.com/",
    "sub": "app|xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "aud": [
        "https://some-org-url",
        "https://auth-app.com/userinfo"
    ],
    "iat": 1660117559,
    "exp": 1660203959,
    "azp": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "scope": "openid profile email"
}
```

I can extract the syntactically valid claims by defining my struct as

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Claims {
    iss: String,
    sub: String,
    aud: Vec<String>,
    iat: u32,
    exp: u32,
    azp: String,
    scope: String
}
```

But I am failing to find a way to extract the remaining claims:

- `https://some-org-url/domain`
- `https://some-org-url/roles`
- `https://some-org-url/tag-list`

i.e. the arbitrary claims that cannot be defined as `struct` fields as-is. Using their path stems (e.g. `domain` or `roles`) does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the default `Deserialize` derive doesn't work for your case, you'll want to implement it for your type yourself.

Comment: Just posted that same answer, thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1):

After stepping throuh `jsonwebtoken::decode` a few times, I realised that it calls `Deserialize` on the `Claims` struct you define, passing in the JWT body as data, therefore you can leverage [serde field aliases](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html) to achieve the desired outcome:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Claims {
    #[serde(alias = "https://some-org-url/domain")]
    domain: String,

    #[serde(alias = "https://some-org-url/roles")]
    roles: Vec<String>,

    #[serde(alias = "https://some-org-url/tag-list")]
    tag_list: Vec<String>,

    iss: String,
    sub: String,
    aud: Vec<String>,
    iat: u32,
    exp: u32,
    azp: String,
    scope: String
}
```

- which works fine.